# Java Script Gross/Net Pay Calculator

Tags: java, javascript, calculator

Hey I have been having trouble getting the code for the calculate button to function with the code I have.For some reason it isn't displaying correctly. When I click the calculate button to figure out the gross pay and net pay, the button does not calculate the gross pay and net in the input boxes. After I enter the hours worked and pay rate.  PLEASE HELP....

```
<html>
<title>Gross Pay and Net Pay.</title>
<h1> Gross Pay and Net Pay.</h1>
<body>
Hours: <input id="hours" type="text"><br>
Rate: <input id="rate" type="text"><br>
Gross: <input id="hours * rate" type="text"><br>
Net: <input id= "gross * .9" type="text"><br>


<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>


<script>

function myFunction() {
var hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
var rate = document.getElementById('rate').value;
var gross = document.getElementById('hours * rate');
var net = document.getElementById('gross * .9 ');


if (gross != null) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    "Your gross pay is $" + gross + ".";
}
 if (net != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 
    "Your net pay is $" + net + ".";
}
}
</script>

<body>
<html>
```

Comment: you have to be more precise in what the problem is. what do you expect to happen and what happens?

Comment: `gross` and `net` should be calculated values. `document.getElementById` is used to get user input, not to calculate values.

Comment: When I click the calculate button to figure out the gross pay and net pay, the button does not calculate the gross pay and net in the input boxes. After I enter the hours worked and pay rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple problems in your code. First one is naming of these two inputs:

```
Gross: <input id="hours * rate" type="text"><br>
Net: <input id= "gross * .9" type="text"><br>
```

As per [HTML specs,](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) rule for id and name are:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

You may just want to call `gross` and `net`:

```
Gross: <input id="gross" type="text"><br>
Net: <input id= "net" type="text"><br>
```

Then replace these lines

```
var gross = document.getElementById('hours * rate');
var net = document.getElementById('gross * .9 ');
```

with

```
var gross = hours * rate;
var net = gross * .9 ;
```